# How to add a small amount of local noise to a path in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, noise

I'm trying to recreate the [xkcd look](https://xkcd.com/1501/). Is there a way I can take a path and apply an effect that makes it look like this?

[image]

I've tried using Effect | Distort & Transform | Roughen but haven't been able to match that look (the uneven twists in different directions, at random intervals).

Comment: Roughen should give similar results. What settings are you using? On a 2pt line using roughen at: Size: 0.01 in - Absolute, Details: 10 /in, Smooth I got pretty close results.

Comment: @AndrewH I think I might have to go with the answer provided by  because using roughen with those settings doesn't find the sweet spot between too little and too much distortion, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "Effect | Distort & Transform | Roughen" gives some nice results when using absolute transformations with low values:

[image]

Process video : https://youtu.be/wmGA8xRSKak

You can also achieve the effect with brushes often found when searching for "Lineart Brushes" or " Ink sketch brushes" which might be a simpler way to do it as you can just apply the brush to your paths.

Some examples can be found here 
*free*

http://vectips.com/tutorials/30-sketchy-style-brushes/
[image: http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/sketchb_00.jpg]

*paid*

http://freebiesdesign.com/17-amazing-illustrator-brushes/